# Net Core deployed app throws error 404 on IIS

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I'm working on a web app with Angular 7 as Front End and Net Core 3.0 as Back End. Everything works fine in development mode and I am able to call the URI from the front end, directly from the browser and from Postman as well https://localhost:5001/api/controller/params

For demonstration purposes I have to do a release right now. From CLI and Visual Studio (Mac) everything looks OK: folder generated with path project/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.0/publish/all the .dll files, web.config, etc.

However, when published on IIS if I call https://appname.myserver.com/api/controller/params or http the browser gives me a 404 error.
If I call http://appname.myserver.com/ I get the blue IIS screen with the welcome message in different languages.

The IIS configuration followed Microsoft instructions found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I'm not publishing directly to IIS since I don't have access to the server, however I did supervise the setup process remotely.

I've looked over the web and someone suggested to do this in my Program.cs file:

```
    namespace BackEnd
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5001");
                });
    }
}
```

And the web.config looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\BackEnd.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Here's the applicationHosting.config:

```
<site name="backendv2.hawk-poslatinoamericana.com.mx" id="10" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="No Managed Code" enabledProtocols="http">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\HostingSpaces\poslatino\backendv2.hawk-poslatinoamericana.com.mx\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="169.57.1.244:5001:backendv2.hawk-poslatinoamericana.com.mx" sslFlags="0" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="169.57.1.244:5000:backendv2.hawk-poslatinoamericana.com.mx" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="169.57.1.244:5000:www.backendv2.hawk-poslatinoamericana.com.mx" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="169.57.1.244:5001:www.backendv2.hawk-poslatinoamericana.com.mx" sslFlags="0" />
            </bindings>
            <logFile directory="C:\HostingSpaces\poslatino\backendv2.hawk-poslatinoamericana.com.mx\logs" enabled="true" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging enabled="true" directory="C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" maxLogFiles="50" />
            <limits connectionTimeout="00:04:00" />
        </site>
```

But so far, no luck and I am out of ideas.

Comment: you want to host your app in iis or Kestrel ?

Comment: I want to host it on IIS

Comment: If you host it on IIS, then the relevant XML elements from IIS applicationHost.config must also be shared as part of the question.

Comment: If you are getting a blue screen with messages which means you are pointing to your machine/server and not your application. If you have hosted your application on https://appname.myserver.com/ (Which is your DNS name), then you have to application path in your URL.
e.g. https://appname.myserver.com/yourApplicationName_IIS/api/controller/params

I hope it will help you!

Comment: I just put the applicationHosting.config, just the part regarding the site in question, please let me know if something else is needed from that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I found you bind the two domain with the 5000 and 5001 port not the 80 port.

If you call `https://appname.myserver.com`, it will access the server's 443 port, not the 5000 and 5001 port. If you call `http://appname.myserver.com`, it will access the server's 80 port.

Besides, if you want to host the asp.net core application in the IIS, you should firtly create the web applicatio  by using below steps:

On the hosting system, create a folder to contain the app's published folders and files. In a following step, the folder's path is provided to IIS as the physical path to the app. For more information on an app's deployment folder and file layout, see ASP.NET Core directory structure.

In IIS Manager, open the server's node in the Connections panel. Right-click the Sites folder. Select Add Website from the contextual menu.

Provide a Site name and set the Physical path to the app's deployment folder. Provide the Binding configuration and create the website by selecting OK:

Notice: the port is 80 not 5001

[image]

Comment: Does it matter if in Program.cs I set the 5000 and 5001 ports?